# Compilation igzip for Windows

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, msys2

good afternoon!
Prompt, please, how to compile [igzip](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/igzip-a-high-performance-deflate-compressor-with-optimizations-for-genomic-data).
At compilation to me gives an error message

```
Lorents@ASUS MINGW32 ~
$ cd /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/igzip

Lorents@ASUS MINGW32 /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/igzip
$ make
mkdir obj0c
Making object file obj0c/common.o
g++ -c -g -D LINUX -I . -I c_code -I ../include -O2 -fPIC -D MAJOR_VERSION=IGZIP0C c_code/common.cpp -o obj0c/common.o
c_code/common.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 /**********************************************************************
 ^
In file included from c_code/common.cpp:38:0:
c_code/bitbuf2.h:30:19: fatal error: types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:240: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «obj0c/common.o»
make: *** [obj0c/common.o] Ошибка 1
```

For compilation I use MSYS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your current error message, make sure that you extracted all of the files and folders from igzip_042.zip to the same place.  So you should actually have the `igzip` folder at `/c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/igzip_042/igzip` and there should be a file named `types.h` in `/c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/igzip_042/include/`.  The `-I ../include` option they are passing to the C compiler tells it where to find `types.h`.

After fixing that, you will get other, unrelated error messages, and you can ask new questions about how to fix them.

Comment: Thank you. There was a new problem. Tell me please.

Comment: Making object file obj0c/crc_utils.o
/nfs/site/disks/iots4/engineering/cai_isa/tools/yasm-hsw/yasm -f x64 -f elf64 -X gnu -g dwarf2 -D LINUX -I . -I c_code -I ../include -D MAJOR_VERSION=IGZIP0C c_code/crc_utils.asm -o obj0c/crc_utils.o
make: /nfs/site/disks/iots4/engineering/cai_isa/tools/yasm-hsw/yasm: Команда не найдена
Makefile:250: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «obj0c/crc_utils.o»
make: *** [obj0c/crc_utils.o] Ошибка 127

Comment: As I said, that's a new, unrelated problem.  You should click the checkmark to mark my answer as the accepted answer and then ask a new, separate question using the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Also, you should try harder to look at the error message yourself and understand what it means and troubleshoot it.